# How to align a logo in a String

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsmutableattributedstring

The currently code allow me to attach a logo. Like this:

But how can I align only the "Logo" sign on the right ?
[image]

That is what I want:
[image]

```
let paragraph = NSMutableAttributedString()

                let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 15.0) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18.0)
                let align = NSTextAlignment.Center

                let textFont = [
                    NSFontAttributeName : font]


                let attrString1 = NSAttributedString(string: "\n Logo", attributes:textFont)
                let attrString2 = NSAttributedString(attributedString: textview.attributedText)


                paragraph.appendAttributedString(attrString2)
                paragraph.appendAttributedString(attrString1)

                let paraStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

                paraStyle.alignment = .Center
                paraStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 15.0
                paraStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore = 3.0


                paragraph.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paraStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0,length: paragraph.length))

                shareTextView.attributedText = paragraph
```

Comment: The "logo" need to be under the String

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. Do you have a logo image that you want to center with below the text? Or are you saying that you want the word "Logo" to have different horizontal alignment than the word "Example"? Can you post a picture of the effect you are after by creating it in a drawing program?

Comment: Question edited @DuncanC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want different alignment for different portions, specify different ranges for the two paragraph styles. Thus, you can do something like:

```
let centerStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
centerStyle.alignment = .Center

let rightStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
rightStyle.alignment = .Right

let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 24.0) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(24.0)
let fontAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : font]

let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Foo\nBar", attributes: fontAttributes)

attributedText.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: centerStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 4))
attributedText.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: rightStyle, range: NSRange(location: 4, length: 3))

textView.attributedText = attributedText
```

Or, easier, you can append attributed strings with different attributes:

```
let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 24.0) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(24.0)
let centerAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : centerStyle]
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Foo\n", attributes: centerAttributes)

let rightAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : rightStyle]
attributedText.appendAttributedString(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Bar", attributes: rightAttributes))

textView.attributedText = attributedText
```

That yields:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to make the 2 parts that have different alignments different paragraphs.

Comment: Can you leave a more detailed answer ? Thank you